# SQL group by week and get the date of start of the week

Tags: sql-server, date, group-by

I have a FiscalCalendar in MS SQL which has FiscalWeek, Week, FiscalMonth, Month, datekey etc. I have joined this table to another table. I am running a query to get the sales data for different categories and grouping them by FiscalWeek. However, in the table, I want to display the first day of the week associated with it. When I add Date to the select and groupby cause, my granularity changes (which I know is wrong)

I want something like this:

[image]

Instead I am getting this when I put date in the select and the group by clause

[image]

Here is my Query:

```
select cal.FiscalYear, cal.FiscalWeek, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cal.Date, 111) AS Date, sum(sd.Used) as Actual, sd.ShipGrp

from ods.adhoc.MktFiscalCalendar as cal,
Details as sd

where cal.daykey=sd.sys1dt
and cal.FiscalYear in ('2018')

Group by cal.FiscalYear, cal.FiscalWeek, Date, sd.ShipGrp
```

Comment: **Please, do not** post sample data, table structure, your code, desired outputs as **images**, instead of that post them as **formatted text**.

Comment: sorry, I was struggling with that

Comment: Do the join as before.  But then you can subquery the result for MIN(date).  If you post your table structure you are joining, and your query then someone will probably show you.

Comment: @Zorkolot It almost worked I used min(conver.... But, my data is not consistent. Data for a few days is missing, because of which the min date is sometimes different. Any work around this.

Comment: I think you would subquery the min date for the matching fiscal year and fiscal week from your calendar. Not the dates from your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cal.FiscalYear
       , cal.FiscalWeek
       , (select min(Date)
        from MktFiscalCalendar
        where FiscalWeek = cal.FiscalWeek
        and FiscalYear = cal.FiscalYear) AS Date,
       , sum(sd.Used)                     AS Actual
       , sd.ShipGrp
FROM   MktFiscalCalendar AS cal,
       Details AS sd
WHERE  cal.daykey = sd.sys1dt
       AND cal.FiscalYear IN ( '2018' )
GROUP  BY cal.FiscalYear
          , cal.FiscalWeek
          , sd.ShipGrp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in a windows function.  Please try something like below.  Note that we remove the date from the group by clause and use the MIN() aggregate function in the SELECT clause.  Partitioning by week, will change the result for each week - be sure to order it or the results can look deceiving.

```
SELECT cal.FiscalYear
       , cal.FiscalWeek
       , MIN(cal.Date)
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY cal.FiscalWeek) AS Date
       , sum(sd.Used)                     AS Actual
       , sd.ShipGrp
FROM   ods.adhoc.MktFiscalCalendar AS cal,
       Details AS sd
WHERE  cal.daykey = sd.sys1dt
       AND cal.FiscalYear IN ( '2018' )
GROUP  BY cal.FiscalYear
          , cal.FiscalWeek
          , sd.ShipGrp
```

Comment: when I use 'OVER' like you said it gives me the group by error :: 

Column 'ods.adhoc.MktFiscalCalendar.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Huh, that's odd.  What version of SQL are you on?  Can you post the new query as you have it?